# Why does GphotoEntry work but PhotoEntry returns empty value in Picasa Web Albums API?

Tags: java, picasa

I have the exact same issue as simplyi has [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-picasa-data-api/browse_thread/thread/3724da6e1231c17a).  It appears he has never been answered and I couldn't find this question on this site so I figured I'd put it before this community.

For whatever reason, GphotoEntry works but a PhotoEntry returns nothing.  I need to use the getMediaSource() method on the PhotoEntry; it's not available for GphotoEntry.

Here's my code (it has to be in a try-catch statement, but I've taken that out here).  You'll noticed that I've commented out the line that works for me:

```
URL baseSearchUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/all");

Query myQuery = new Query(baseSearchUrl);
myQuery.setStringCustomParameter("kind", "photo");
myQuery.setMaxResults(10);
myQuery.setFullTextQuery("puppy");

AlbumFeed searchResultsFeed = myService.query(myQuery, AlbumFeed.class);

//for (GphotoEntry photo : searchResultsFeed.getEntries()) {
for (PhotoEntry photo : searchResultsFeed.getPhotoEntries()) {
     System.out.println(photo.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.

Solution:
Once you add the `photos-meta.jar` to your classpath, it should work.

[Here is information source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-picasa-data-api/GphotoEntry%2420/google-picasa-data-api/nznClK-qLG4/45hTN1kKyv0J)

Answer (score 0):

For Android, u should use GPhoto, as for Java, u can use PhotoEntry or AlbumEntry.

Maybe Google update new version for Picasa Web Album API,
So there are many new class here, GPhoto is the first one.